# Backpatching Intermediate Code Generation For Boolean Expressions

Tags: compiler-construction

I´m studying the Dragon Book to create an intermediate code generator for my DECAF compiler.

I´m reading the backpatching method, which suggest the following translation of boolean expressions:

[image]

I find everything very clear. However, when implementing my translator based on the book I´ve found a problem when having if statements such as:

```
boolean a = false;
if(a){
    x= 0;
}
```

The problem I have is that I don´t know how to manage variables in a boolean expression where there is no operand. When I have things like:

```
if(x>200){
   ....
}
```

The translation works fine. Can anyone tell what to do in the case I have a single variable as a control-flow boolean expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to emit some sort of test-and-jump operator. For example, you could pretend that `if(a)` were the same as `if(a!=0)` (with appropriate type safety, but still assuming that in your VM boolean false is `0`) and proceed in a fashion similar to the E1 relop E2 case. (Here E1 would be the expression and E2 a literal 0.)

The Dragon book example doesn't contemplate boolean variables; note that it effectively constant-folds `true` and `false`. That's probably effective for didactic purposes; in a real programming language, boolean types would have to have some kind of integer representation, and boolean variables would need to be tested appropriately.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.One more question:  I will have to do the same thing for methodCalls right?

Comment: @PabloEstrada: I wouldn't special case variables. You'd use this for any expression other than a relational or boolean expression. (That might force you to explicitly constant-fold.)

Comment: @PabloEstrada: Rici is right.  You'd really want "B -> E" as the additional grammar rule, with a type check that E produces a boolean result type.  I answered your literal question.

Answer (score 1):

Add "B -> variable" to your grammar rules.

Then set up the patching for it analogously to rule 5.